# Reference generic comment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, xml-comments, xml-documentation

I was wondering if it is possible to reference a dynamic generic class name in a comment and have it conditionally resolved in the IDE?

Simple base class example:

```
// <summary>
// Retrieves all <T> members from the database.
// </summary>
public void GetAll<T>()
{
 //magic
}
```

If I now inherit from this class and  happens to be class **User** then I'd like to have IntelliSense show my comment as "Retrieves all User members from the database".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way of getting Intellisense to automatically write the name of the generic type used for your specific call. The best you can do is use the [`typeparamref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173192.aspx) tag, which indicates to Visual Studio (and more importantly any docmentation generator) that you are referring to a generic type parameter (`T` in this case).

```
// <summary>
// Retrieves all <typeparamref name="T"/> members from the database.
// </summary>
public void GetAll<T>()
{
    //magic
}
```